# Python Requests Proxy

Tags: python, proxy, python-requests

I am trying to use the Requests module send a post request with a proxy.

My code is this:

```
import requests
proxyList = {'http' : 'http://202.134.202.226:80'}
dataDict = {'input' : 'test'}
r = requests.post('ThePlaceIWantToSendItTo', data=dataDict, proxies=proxyList)
print r.text
```

but when I do this my webserver says i'm still on my home IP meaning the proxy did not work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is `ThePlaceIWantToSendItTo` http?  If it was https it wouldn't be proxied as you've only set a proxy for http.

Comment: Your web server will always tell you that you are on your home network, because that is where it is located. What the proxy does is it changes the ip address from the point of view of an external server. For instance if you are accessing google from the server, google will see the ip address of the proxy server, not your server's ip because that is where the traffic is coming from. Where as your servers ip address does not actually change.

Comment: I'm referring to a webserver that i've started with Putty, its hosted on an external server

Comment: ok sorry. You might want to clarify that in your question.

Comment: Try sending a request to http://www.whatismyip.com/. If the proxy is working, your IP would be different there.

Comment: @VincentBeltman It seems that I'll be forbidden if a request with a proxy was sent to that site, with a 403 as a response.

Comment: If I send a request to http://httpbin.org/get the origin in the response will show two IPs: one is my IP and the other is the proxy.